# Is there any way to check for string either it is null or blank?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any way to check for string either it is null or blank("") in c#?

Currently I have to check two conditions first for `null` and other for blank value

```
if(val == "" || val == null)
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net has provided default function for this purpose you should use like this.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty("any string"))
{
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand why this selected as an answer. [bejger's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21773154/447156) has a better explanation, has more upvotes and more faster. If you stuck between multiple answer to choose one, always choose which answer has a better quality. Quality should always win..

Comment: i am new on this forum when i saw mr Ahsan answer i marked him as answer. and tries to mark some other really great answer including bejger's answer then i was unable to mark as it first said please wait for 15 minute to select answer then after 15 minute it said you can just select once.

Thanks to everyone who helped me so fast.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` method which checks for string references that are **null or have no data**:

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
{
    return true;
}
```

There is also a method `String.IsNullOrWhitespace()` which indicates whether a specified string is **null**, **empty**, **or consists only of white-space characters**.

```
if(String.IsNullOrWhitespace(val))
{
    return true;
}
```

The above is a shortcut for the following code:

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(val) || val.Trim().Length == 0)
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`String.IsNullOrEmpty` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> Indicates whether the specified string is **null** or **an empty string**.

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: not from C#, if I also wants to return False then can I use `return String.IsNullOrEmpty(val);`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Sure. Since `IsNullOrEmpty` returns `boolean`, you can use it whatever as you want. But remember, since we don't know the rest of OP's code, if `String.IsNullOrEmpty(val)` returns `false`, we don't know he/she returns `false` or not outside this _if statement_.

Answer (score 2):

There is easiest and simple way.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty("Val")) //This condition comparing both NULL and EMPTY also
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.IsNullOrEMpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).